# How to find out the class when we do mouse hover on the tab

Tags: jquery

I want to highlight the clicked li tab

When i do hover on the tab its being highligted , could you please tell me how to add that class when clicked on li tab

i have tried adding class active

Some pat of my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 fetchTopLosersData('#1d');
    $("ul.menu li").click(function() {

    $("ul.menu li").removeClass("active");
$(this).addClass("active");


        var tabclicked = $(this).find("a").attr("href");
        $('.tab-container-1').find('.tab-content-1').hide().html('');
        $(tabclicked).show();
        fetchTopLosersData(tabclicked);
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gr1L23us/19/

Comment: Your js is right, but need to add css; .menu li a:hover, .menu li.active a {  fiddle update: https://jsfiddle.net/gr1L23us/20/

Answer (score 0):

Just add the css li.active a

```
.menu li a:hover,
.menu li.active a {
  background: #528CBF;
}

.menu li a:hover {
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gr1L23us/21/

Answer (score 0):

Your `js` is ok. Just use following `css`.

```
.menu li.active a{
    background: #528cbf;
    transition: all 0.3s ease 0s;  
}
```